# Context-Free Grammar to Pushdown (Stack) Automata

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, context-free-grammar

Given the following problem:

> Convert the following Context-Free Grammar specification to it's corresponding Pushdown (Stack) Automata.

$$
G = (N, \sum , P, S) \\
N = \{ S, A \} \\
\sum = \{ 0, 1 \} \\
P = \{ S \rightarrow 0S1, S \rightarrow A, A \rightarrow 1A0, A \rightarrow S, A \rightarrow \epsilon \}
$$

When constructing the automata, I know that each operation is of the the form $\alpha ; \beta ; \delta$ where:

- $\alpha$: the input value
- $\beta$: the value to be checked or removed from the stack
- $\delta$: the value to be inserted into the stack

But in the Grammar for example, if I am correct:

- $S \rightarrow 0S1$: is a movement given an input of $0$, move to the state $S$ and insert the value $1$ into the stack. But what value do I check for in the stack or does this mean that it does not matter what value is at the top of the stack?
- $A \rightarrow \epsilon$: Is to ignore what is at the top of the stack (not remove anything). But does this mean that the input does not matter and I do not insert anything into the stack? Also, which state am I to move to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$M=(Q,\  \Sigma,\  \Gamma,\  \delta, \ q_{0},\ Z, \ F)$$
$$Q = \{q\}, \Sigma = \{0, 1\}, \Gamma = \{S, A, 0, 1\}, q_{0} = q, Z = S, F = \{q\}$$
$$\delta(q, \epsilon, S) = \{(q, A),(q, 0S1)\}$$
$$\delta(q, \epsilon, A) = \{(q, S),(q, 1A0),(q, \epsilon)\}$$
$$\delta(q,0,0) = (q, \epsilon)$$
$$\delta(q,1,1) = (q, \epsilon)$$

With:

- $Q$ the set of states.
- $\Sigma$ input alphabet
- $\Gamma$ stack alphabet
- $\delta$ transition relation.
- $q_{0}$ start state.
- $Z$ initial stack symbol.
- $F$ accepting states.

Comment: But isn't $\{ S, A \}$ the set of states?

Comment: no, in my solution I have only one state which is q, S and A are here only stack symbols.
There is an algorithm for that but I couldn't find it in a good source online. In short, all terminals and non-terminals should be added as stack symbols and you need only one state say q.
for every rule S->[something] you should have $\delta (q, \epsilon, S) = (q, [something])$ and for each alphabet symbol a you have $\delta (q, a,a) = (q, \epsilon)$